# can't use a scope on ruby on rails 4.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I tried to build a scope for my job class like this:

```
 class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
   scope :most_recent, -> {order("created_at_DESC")}
   validates_presence_of :description, :title
 end
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Jobs#premium
Showing c:/Users/Suporte 2/classificado/job_board/app/views/jobs/premium.html.erb where line #3 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: created_at_DESC: SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  WHERE "jobs"."premium" = 't'  ORDER BY created_at_DESC
Extracted source (around line #3):
1
2
3
4
5
6

  <h1>Premium jobs</h1>

  <%= render @jobs %>

  <br>


Rails.root: c:/Users/Suporte 2/classificado/job_board

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/jobs/premium.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_jobs_premium_html_erb__296098893_30761424'
```

Here's my index function at jobs_controller.rb :

```
def premium
  @jobs = Job.where(premium: true).all.most_recent
end
```

And my premium.html.erb archive :

```
 <h1>Premium jobs</h1>

 <%= render @jobs %>

 <br>

 <%= link_to 'New Job', new_job_path %>
 <br>

 <%= link_to 'Hello World', hello_world_path %>
 <%= link_to 'All Jobs', jobs_path %>
```

I'm using rails version 4.1.4, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: created_at_DESC

This line in your Job model

`scope :most_recent, -> {order("created_at_DESC")}`

should be

```
scope :most_recent, -> {order("created_at DESC")}
```